# Your child might/could do better

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *Your child **might** do better if she got/had a different teacher.*
2. *Your child **could** do better if she got/had a different teacher.*

Q: Are 1) and 2) both **pure second conditionals** or is sentence 1) a **mixed 1st/2nd conditional**?

Comment: The categorization of conditionals is not something done by most native speakers. It's a generalization that is often incomplete or confusing (mostly only provided by ESL teachers and texts), and it's certainly not a strict rule. It serves only as a guidepost.

Answer (score 1):

I found these two explanations that might help you: [Conditional forms](https://www.businessenglishresources.com/learn-english-for-business/student-section/student-handouts/forming-conditionals-english-student-guide/) & [mixed conditional](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/mixed-conditional/)

From what I understand from those two sites, the answer would be that 1 and 2 are both pure second conditionals since the result clause is "might" and the conditional clause is in the simple past!

Though I'm a bit confused as to why it's "got/had", "got" doesn't make any sense to me, so I answered your question by assuming the conditional clause is "if she had a different teacher".

Comment: *Got* makes perfect sense. It means "arranged to have" or "was given."

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't get that right away, thanks!